# how to calculate when two simultaneously increasing numbers will reach a certain ratio

Tags: percentages

Say i'm playing a game that has two outcomes: win or lose.

Every round I calculate the win percentage by dividing the the number of wins by the total number of rounds played.

1/1 ＝ 100%  |  1/2 ＝ 50%   |   39/100 ＝ 39%  |   152/400 ＝ 38%

Let's say my latest "score" is this last ration: 145/400 ＝ 38%,
and i would like to calculate how many games I need to win consecutively in order to reach a certain percentage, say 40%?

I tried to work it out myself but I'm just not getting to any solution. I'm not sure if there's a formula or whether it is something very trivial and i'm simply not seeing it.

Is there a formula or a method to calculate it? 
I'd appreciate any insight. Thanks

Comment: 145 / 250 is .58 not .38

Comment: Typo. thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Eli A

I think what you want is something like this:

Supposing you had 151 wins out of 400 rounds and would like to get to 40% wins by winning several games consecutively.

Let x be the number of wins needed,

$\frac{151+x}{400+x}=\frac{2}{5}$

solving gives x = 15, so you need 15 consecutive wins.

To check

151 + 15 = 166

400 + 15 = 415

166 / 415 = .4 or 40% win rate.

Comment: Spot on! thanks.

Comment: I'm not good at maths, HOW do you actually solve this equation? how do you get the value of X?